# Seeding in Rails 5 with has_one and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Still new to rails, and I'm confused on the best way to seed this. I havent created the user yet, but basically a client belongs to a user, as does a partner. A partner has many clients, but a client only has 1 partner.

Creating the partner is fine, but I'm trying to create 5 clients under each partner as well.

Any suggestions on how to do this? What I have started is below.

```
require 'faker'

10.times do |partner|
  Partner.create!(
  user_id: Faker::Number.unique.digit,
  first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
  last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
  company: Faker::Company.name,
  phone: Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone,
  email: Faker::Internet.email

  5.times do |client|
    Partner.client.create!(
      first_name: Faker::Name.first_name)
  end
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
require 'faker'

10.times do
  partner = Partner.create!(
  user_id: Faker::Number.unique.digit,
  first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
  last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
  company: Faker::Company.name,
  phone: Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone,
  email: Faker::Internet.email)

  5.times do
    partner.clients.create!(first_name: Faker::Name.first_name)
  end
end
```

Edit: my earlier answer was incorrect. Fixed now.